# Algorithm to find number of corners and other characteristics/features of an image? (OCR, letter recognition)

Tags: ocr, feature-detection

I am working on a simple OCR application (I know there already exist applications and technologies much better than what I will ever be able to develop, but it's for fun). My approach is to compare a scanned character with a training set of known characters by comparing certain characteristics of the images, such as:

1. Width, Height
2. Number of painted pixels
3. Number of corners
4. etc.

Can someone tell me algorithms for 3. and 4. (pseudocode is fine)?

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this out

private function getCornerType($im, $x, $y)
{

```
    $p11 = $this->getBWcolor($im, $x, $y);
    $p21 = $this->getBWcolor($im, $x+1, $y);
    $p12 = $this->getBWcolor($im, $x, $y+1);
    $p22 = $this->getBWcolor($im, $x+1, $y+1);

    $sum = $p11 + $p12 + $p21 + $p22;

    if ($sum % 2 == 0){
        return false;
    }


    if (($p11==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p21==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p12==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p22==COLOR_WHITE)){
        return CORNER_BP_LEFT_TOP;
    }

    if (($p11==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p21==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p12==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p22==COLOR_WHITE)){
        return CORNER_BP_RIGHT_TOP;
    }

    if (($p11==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p21==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p12==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p22==COLOR_WHITE)){
        return CORNER_BP_LEFT_BOTTOM;
    }

    if (($p11==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p21==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p12==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p22==COLOR_BLACK)){
        return CORNER_BP_RIGHT_BOTTOM;
    }

    if (($p11==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p21==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p12==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p22==COLOR_BLACK)){
        return CORNER_WP_LEFT_TOP;
    }

    if (($p11==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p21==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p12==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p22==COLOR_BLACK)){
        return CORNER_WP_RIGHT_TOP;
    }

    if (($p11==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p21==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p12==COLOR_WHITE)&&($p22==COLOR_BLACK)){
        return CORNER_WP_LEFT_BOTTOM;
    }

    if (($p11==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p21==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p12==COLOR_BLACK)&&($p22==COLOR_WHITE)){
        return CORNER_WP_RIGHT_BOTTOM;
    }

}
```

#### hope this works